# sed path parsing is not working

Tags: regex, unix, sed

`pwd | sed "s%^\(/[^/]*/\).*?\(/[^/]+\)$%\1...\2%"`

I am not sure why this does not work. I have tried both the greedy and non greedy star after the first capture group. I am not even using lookaheads or anything. It works in regex testers. I'm trying to grab the first and last text-part of a path (to squish it while still providing an idea of what dir I'm in).

This is for a tmux prompt line so I'm kind of trying to avoid bringing in something heavyweight like perl to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [parameter expansions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)? Parameter expansions cost *way* less processing power than a command, pipe and external command you have there:

```bash
start="${PWD#/}"; start="${start%%/*}"
end="${PWD/*\//}"
printf '/%s/…/%s $ ' "$start" "$end"
```

Comment: What is this sorcery? First time I've seen it. Looks like some sort of thing **designed to do what I want**. *emotes*

Comment: @StevenLu I added a link to the answer to describe the sorcery.

Answer (score 0):

I got it after a few more tries:

`pwd | sed "s%^\(/[^/]*/\).*\(/[^/]*\)$%\1...\2%"`